# Automapper ignoring Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, automapper

**Issue**

**AutoMapper v10.1.1**

I have an AutoMapper profile that requires an extension method (in this case **NickName()**) from it's source to complete the mapping. This method will deliberately throw a **NullReferenceException** to illustrate the point that AutoMapper seems to be swallowing this exception. It never gets raised when the mapper is called from my service (**MyService**).

**Example**

A call to

```
mapper.Map<Person>(person)
```

will return a Person object with the Name property populated and the NickName property set to null despite the fact a NullReferenceException was thrown in the mapping process.

**Mapping Profile**

```
public class PersonMappingProfile : Profile
{
  CreateMap<DataStorePerson, Person>()
    .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Name))
    .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.NickName, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.NickName()));
}
```

**Service**

```
public class MyService()
{
   private IMapper mapper;

   public MyService(IMapper mapper)
   {
      this.mapper = mapper;
   }
   
   public Person GetPerson()
   {
       var person = dataStore.GetPerson();
       return mapper.Map<Person>(person); // EXPECTED NULL REF EXCEPTION to be thrown here
   }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
   public static string NickName(this DataStorePerson person)
   {
      throw new NullRefenceException("This exception is swallowed by AutoMapper");
   }   
}
```

How do I get AutoMapper to throw the exception back to the caller?

Comment: Just don't use an extension method.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: I've moved your question sentence to a place where it's obvious. It looked very much like a bug report at first glance because I couldn't find the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get the null reference exception to be raised was if the call to the extension method was wrapped in a ValueResolver. See [Automapper Value Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) .... my mapping profile then had this code `.ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.NickName, options => options.MapFrom<MyCustomResolver>();`

Answer (score 2):

According to [AutoMapper docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper), swallowing the null reference exception is by design, but there is a way around it which has been alluded to already:

> AutoMapper will ignore null reference exceptions when mapping your source to your target. This is by design. If you don’t like this approach, you can combine AutoMapper’s approach with custom value resolvers if needed.